# Did any Western country condemn Japan for pursuing energy deals with Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations, international, japan

> Although Japan has reduced its Russian energy imports since Moscow's
> invasion of Ukraine in February 2022, it has kept stakes in several
> fossil fuel projects in the country for its energy security.
>
> "The project is an extremely important source in terms of stable
> energy supply for Japan," Nakanishi, whose company holds a 10% stake
> in the Gazprom-led GAZP.MM Sakhalin-2 LNG project in Russia's far
> east, told a briefing.
>
> "We are carefully watching the situation," he added.
>
> Japan reduced LNG purchases from Russia by 11% last year to 6.1
> million metric tons, with supplies otherwise dominated by Australia
> and Malaysia. Moscow remains Japan's third biggest LNG supplier with a
> 9% share last year.
>
> The United States, Japan's closest ally and from whom it has increased
> LNG purchases by nearly 34% last year, has recently paused approvals
> for new LNG export licences.
>
> Last week, Japan's Mitsui & Co 8031.Tsaid it has put aside 13.6
> billion yen ($91 million) in additional provisions on its minority
> stake in the U.S.-sanctioned Arctic LNG 2 project led by Russian
> private gas producer Novatek NVTK.MM.

https://www.naturalgasworld.com/mitsubishi-sees-russias-sakhalin-lng-as-key-energy-source-for-japan-109575

Did any Western country condemn Japan for pursuing energy deals with Russia? I am surprised that although Japan reduced its Russian energy imports, it has kept stakes in several fossil fuel projects in Russia for its energy security. Did any Western country condemn Japan for doing so?

Comment: You're kinda assuming that everyone in Japan is comfy with those projects still, which might not be the case. "Japan's Mitsui and Co 8031.T has decided to pull its employees out of Russia's Arctic LNG 2 liquefied natural gas (LNG) project, the Sankei newspaper reported on Tuesday, citing several sources, in yet another blow for the project." https://www.reuters.com/markets/commodities/russian-arctic-lng-2-project-targeted-by-us-sanctions-2023-12-26/

Comment: TotalEnergies also has a 10% share in that Arctic project, just like the Japanese firms, so one might guess France didn't criticize that (although some French politicians were implicitly critical of TotalEnergies' participation in Azerbaijan.) Anyhow, it's obvious the US doesn't like that Russian Arctic project since they sanctioned it. Loud condemnations of Japan/France participation might not be heard, but are a bit obvious/implicit in the sanctions.

Comment: US sanctions appear to [prevent](https://www.reuters.com/business/energy/totalenergies-initiates-force-majeure-russias-arctic-lng-2-2024-01-16/) TotalEnergies from getting any profit off that project, so while they may put a brave face about it and [trumpet](https://totalenergies.com/media/video/arctic-lng-2-vast-lng-project-russias-far-north) the tech achievement... they were pretty much left holding the bag.